# How can I make a word as an answer in int(input);

Tags: python, if-statement, input, int

```pythin
import time
import random

lista=('ACE','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','BOY','LADY','KING')
print('You have got',random.choice(lista))
i=int(input('Do you want to get a new card'))
YES=1
if i == YES:
    print('Your second card is:',random.choice(lista))
```

I want to make a `YES` as an answer but it doesn't work. Can you explain to me how I can do it?

Comment: *What* doesn't work? Are you typing `YES` or `1` at the prompt?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import time
import random
lista=('ACE','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','BOY','LADY','KING')
print('You have got',random.choice(lista))

i = input('Do you want to get a new card: ')

if i == "YES":
    print('Your second card is:',random.choice(lista))
```

You were using "Yes" (a string) as an integer, you cannot compare an integer with a string.

Comment: The comparison would never happen, because you can't convert `"YES"` to an `int` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

This Will Work

```
import time
import random

lista=('ACE','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','BOY','LADY','KING')
print('You have got',random.choice(lista))

i = input('Do you want to get a new card: ')

if i == "YES":
    print('Your second card is:',random.choice(lista))
```

Please take `i` as str input and then apply the `if` operation.

Comment: You don't need to call `str`, because `input` already returns a `str`.

Comment: I have changed it @chepner